# Can you mock C functions with Googlemock without creating a global mock instance?

Tags: c++, c, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

The generally used approach of wrapping free C functions in a "Mockinterface" class with a child class "Mock"(that calls MOCK_METHOD) results in the need of a global mock variable in order to use it in a TEST.

Is there another design approach that does not need a global Mock object/pointer so we could use a local Mock object in TEST?

Comment: Why is this tagged C++?

Comment: @tadman because googlemock only works c++ based.

Comment: If anyone has suggestions on how to improve the question, please tell me. Currently I think that it is quite relevant for a good design (avoiding global variables) and the solution is not obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter whether the mock object is globally static, locally static, or locally dynamic. You just need to make sure that it exists when the mocked C function is called and wants to call the method of the mock object.

The important part is that the per-se static C functions need to access that mock object. In consequence you need *some kind* of static variable. It does not need to be the mock object.

I realized this with a class variable (in contrast to a member variable) that stores a pointer to the single mock object. If you are sure that at most one mock object exists at a time, you can even save some effort because of possibly multiple instantiations.

For example:

```cpp
class FunctionsMock
{
public:
    static FunctionsMock* instance;

    FunctionsMock()
    {
        instance = this;
    }

    ~FunctionsMock()
    {
        instance = nullptr;
    }

    MOCK_METHOD(int, function1, (int p));

    MOCK_METHOD(void, function2, ());
};
```

An implementation can look like:

```cpp
FunctionsMock* FunctionsMock::instance = nullptr;

extern "C" int function1(int p)
{
    if (FunctionsMock::instance == nullptr)
    {
        ADD_FAILURE() << "FunctionsMock::instance == nullptr";
        return 0; // some sensible value
    }
    return FunctionsMock::instance->function1(p);
}

extern "C" void function2()
{
    ASSERT_NE(FunctionsMock::instance, nullptr);
    FunctionsMock::instance->function2();
}
```

*Note: Since you cannot use `ASSERT_NE` in a function that returns a value, you need to check the condition explicitly and in case call `ADD_FAILURE`.*

Now you can define a local mock object and check that expected functions are called:

```cpp
TEST(SuiteName, TestName)
{
    FunctionsMock mock;

    EXPECT_CALL(mock, function1(...
    EXPECT_CALL(mock, function2())...

    // ...
}
```

If you want multiple concurrent mock objects, the C functions needs to know which mock object has to be used. I did not dive into this since we did not need it. All our tests run sequentially. You might want to do some research, depending on the kind of multitasking you do.

If you just want to use the latest instance, you can provide a static stack of mock object pointers instead of the single pointer.

Comment: I really like your solution! I didnt come up with the "instance = this;" - simple, but does the job :) One improvement would be very helpful though, which is enabling multi instantiation. Do you have a suggestion how to implement this? I initially thought of having members instance1,instance2,instance3, the higher numbered instance is used if the previous instance is unequal nullptr(check in constructor) or something like this - but it doesnt seem like a clean solution.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will probably try out a static vector of mock-pointers.